# How to get the name of a place in Nokia Maps on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps, here-api

I want to get the name of a place (similar to Foursquare or Google Maps) from my current location using Maps API in Windows Phone 8. I can already get my current location using the code from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735578%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) tutorial.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ReverseGeocodeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.reversegeocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class.

```
var rgc = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
rgc.QueryCompleted += rgc_QueryCompleted;
rgc.GeoCoordinate = myGeoCoord; //or create new gc with your current lat/lon info 
rgc.QueryAsync();
```

You can then get the data from within your `rgc_QueryCompleted` event handler using the [Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj208540%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property of the event args passed in.

Comment: can you explain me more about this?

Comment: What would you like to know? It's simply creating a new object, attaching the event handler so that you know when it's completed, setting the coordinate to look for and then starting the process.

Answer (score 1):

If @keyboardP answer wasn't sufficient enough, here's (hopefully) working example to get the information about your location. There's no "name" property you could look up, at least not from the API's side.

```
public async Task<MapLocation> ReverseGeocodeAsync(GeoCoordinate location)
{
    var query = new ReverseGeocodeQuery { GeoCoordinate = location };

    if (!query.IsBusy)
    {
        var mapLocations = await query.ExecuteAsync();
        return mapLocations.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return null;
}
```

For this to work you'll need to add the following extension method for async query (from [compiledexperience.com blog](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/async-geocode-query))

```
public static class GeoQueryExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(this Query<T> query)
    {
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        EventHandler<QueryCompletedEventArgs<T>> handler = null;

        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            query.QueryCompleted -= handler;

            if (args.Cancelled)
                taskSource.SetCanceled();
            else if (args.Error != null)
                taskSource.SetException(args.Error);
            else
                taskSource.SetResult(args.Result);
        };

        query.QueryCompleted += handler;
        query.QueryAsync();

        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```